# Devise delete link for an object causes user to sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am having a weird issue with Devise. I have lists with tasks on them. When you delete a task all of the sudden I get a template error having to do with the User.

It seems like the delete method causes the session to logout and therefore can't find the User when trying to load the template.

I have no idea why this is happening:

_task.html

```
<div class="tasks">
<%= div_for task do %>

<%= link_to 'Delete', task_path(task), :method => :delete, :class => "delete", :remote  => true %> | <%= content_tag(:div, task.task, :class => "task-body") %> 


<% end %>
</div>
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#task_<%= @task.id %>").fadeOut();
```

ERROR AFTER RELOADING PAGE, THIS IS FOR THE ACCOUNT, LOGOUT ETC in HEADER

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}

Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <div id ="login">
3: <ul>
4:  <li><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %></li>
5:    <li><%= link_to "Account", user_path(current_user) %></li>
6:  <li><%= link_to "Things", user_things_path(current_user) %></li>
7:  
8: </ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the relevants code from the routes and the controller?

Comment: Which versions of rails and devise are you using?

Comment: I'm seeing this problem as well.  When calling a destroy method for a nested resource of the user object, the user gets signed out.  I have the latest version of devise and Rails.

Answer (score 1):

After a little more searching I found the answer here on stackoverflow, so credit should go to justsee from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129524/rails-session-gets-destroy-whenever-model-destroy-link-is-clicked)

> The request will not include the required CSRF data, and as of
>   Rails 3.0.4 the session is silently reset instead of throwing an
>   ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error.
>   To fix this include the following in your layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> 
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```