# current_user resets when deleting a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am running into an issue when I delete any resource. Before I delete something, current_user returns the correct User; however, after I delete something, current_user returns nill. I tried this with multiple resources and it does the same thing. Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem?

EDIT: I also created a UsersController to allow me to manage the users. My routes file contains:

```
resources :users
devise_for :users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution: my layout did not have `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`. Found answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129524/rails-session-gets-destroy-whenever-model-destroy-link-is-clicked)